# How do I get a template class to take an array of any size as argument?

Tags: c++, templates

How can I make a class with template argument that takes an array of any size? I want to pass the array as a template argument so that I can hash the string at compile-time, something like this:

```
template <typename>
struct CharArrayWrapper
{
    
};

template <typename T, int N>
struct CharArrayWrapper<T[N]>
{
    static constexpr int stringLen() { N - 1; }
};
```

Comment: In modern C++ you shouldn't need any of this. Just write the hash function as usual, slap `constexpr` onto it, and it might work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

This looks quite ugly to me, but it seems to work: https://godbolt.org/z/cd96Pjsdj

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct MyArray
{
    explicit MyArray(T (&data)[N]) : data_{data} {}
    size_t size() const noexcept { return N; }
    const T* get() const noexcept { return data_; }
private:
    T (&data_)[N]{};
};

int main()
{
    const char ac[]{"hey joe"};  // array of chars
    MyArray tac{ac};  // templated array of chars
    std::cout << "tac: " << tac.size() << ", " << tac.get() << "\n";

    const int ai[]{1, 2, 3};  // array of ints
    MyArray tai{ai};  // templated array of ints
    std::cout << "tai: " << tai.size() << ", ";
    std::for_each(tai.get(), tai.get() + tai.size(), [](auto i){ std::cout << i << " "; });
}

// Outputs:
//     tac: 8, hey joe
//     tai: 3, 1 2 3
```

If you actually want a version that makes a copy of your array into the templated struct: https://godbolt.org/z/rs5zs6Ysr

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct MyArray
{
    explicit MyArray(const T (&data)[N]) { std::copy(data, data + N, data_); }
    size_t size() const noexcept { return N; }
    const T* get() const noexcept { return data_; }
private:
    T data_[N]{};
};

int main()
{
    char ac[]{"hey joe"};  // array of chars
    MyArray tac{ac};  // templated array of chars
    ac[0] = 'H';
    std::cout << "ac: " << sizeof(ac)/sizeof(char) << ", " << ac << "\n";
    std::cout << "tac: " << tac.size() << ", " << tac.get() << "\n";


    int ai[]{1, 2, 3};  // array of ints
    MyArray tai{ai};  // templated array of ints
    ai[0] = 10;
    std::cout << "ai: " << tai.size() << ", ";
    std::for_each(ai, ai + sizeof(ai)/sizeof(int), [](auto i){ std::cout << i << " "; });
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "tai: " << tai.size() << ", ";
    std::for_each(tai.get(), tai.get() + tai.size(), [](auto i){ std::cout << i << " "; });
    std::cout << "\n";
}

// Outputs:
//     ac: 8, Hey joe
//     tac: 8, hey joe
//     ai: 3, 10 2 3 
//     tai: 3, 1 2 3
```

Note I added `const` to the type of the `data` parameter. Otherwise, when passing **const** arrays to the constructor, the deduced type `T` would be `const`, preventing the member `data_` to be modified.

---

The idea for this solution comes from Scott Meyer's Effective Modern C++ book, Item 1 (Deducing Types), and a section talking about Array Arguments; there you can see the following code snippet:

```
// return size of an array as a compile-time 
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t arraySize(T (&)[N]) noexcept {
    return N;
}
```

The explanation, also from the book, would be:

- Functions can declare parameters that are references to arrays.
- In this case, **the type deduced for `T` is the actual type of the array**.
- **That type includes the size of the array**, so in my example, `T` is deduced to be `const char [8]` (for the array of chars `ac`), and the type of the parameter `data` (a reference to this array) is `const char (&)[8]`.